# How can I share a class definition over multiple server instances?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

The solution I am working on consists of modules that are decoupled across multiple virtual server instances. All of the modules require the exact same DTO (Data transfer object) classes. Currently I am packaging the DTOs into a library and deploying it to all server modules, when a change is made to the DTOs I have to redeploy the library to all the modules to ensure they are using the latest update.

Are there any technologies or concepts available to share class definitions across multiple server instances without having to redeploy the library manually each time a change occurs?

Comment: You *could* try to serialize the class definition using pickle, then pass it over the wire and dynamically reload it, but that is going to be a very complicated and error-prone solution.  Or load the class remotely using mutliprocess Managers, but again, error prone, and that will have a performance impact.  Generally speaking, if you change your code, you redeploy your code.  You could ease the process by using something like fabric, puppet, or chef though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to share modules across servers without redeploying would be some sort of shared filesystem (NFS, Samba/CIFS, etc...).  One thing to explore is whether SaltStack might work for you. It would require deploying, but it would make such deployments a snap -- http://www.saltstack.com/